# DOMError localforage indexeddb cases?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, indexeddb, localforage

Today I had an error type: DOMerror exception thrown. Leaving the browser in blank page.

After doing some research I see in w3c that it should be used exclusively for indexeddb exceptions.
I actually removed cookies clear local storage and cache. And the problem does not happen anymore.

This is some more information I have of this Issue in the moment it happen:

message: "The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2)."

(anonymous function)@app.js?0.1:1

(anonymous function)@vendors.js?0.1:16229

flush@vendors.js?0.1:16513

drainQueue@vendors.js?0.1:14819 DOMError

Where vendors is third party libraries in a bundle, and app is my application bundle.

I am trying to reproduce the error right now, but is hard to reproduce as it looks like a bad handling with persistance data on client, and the client has cleaned cookies / cache / localstorage to keep on working.

**When does Dom error exception thrown on an application when using localforage?**

Comment: Con you give some more details about what is in the DOMerror? this will reveal what is going wrong.

Comment: Sure @KristofDegrave this is all information I have for the moment until it happens again. What would be nice is to know in which moment a localforage application can throw a DOMError exception in order to use a try catch or handle this situation and reproduce it again.

Answer (score 1):

"The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2)." 
--> this means your indexeddb database is currently in version 2 and you are trying to open it in version 1.

It is not allowed to open a database in a lower version when working with indexeddb

Comment: Do you know how to set the version of indexddb in order to reproduce this case with localforage?

Comment: I don't knop the case with localforage, but normally the version change in the indexeddb API is triggered when opening the database indexeddb.open(name, version). At first sight at the framework, I guess it is doen in the config of localforage

Comment: Great thank you @KristofDegrave I will make a test on this in order to reproduce the case with and without localforage

Comment: you can always delete the existing database with indexedDB.deleteDatabase("databasename")